# I am post-blocked on the Unix & Linux forum

Tags: discussion, support

How can I undo this issue? I know I wrote sucky or idiotic questions at some point or another... I would like to re-enable this ability, as I didn't really care to ask a question on super-user

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998

Comment: There may be a language issue here, since "re-enabling sucky or idiotic questions" isn't the goal of the site.

Comment: I am just wanting to get to post... That's it, I had to post on super user and that doesn't fit catagorically. But, people were willing to be nice to me and help me........

Comment: I had deleted my downvoted posts because I couldn't figure out how to explain what I wanted to do. That was years ago. Now that I actually need this community, I guess I'm stuck unable to contribute to the community, and unable to do anything else... I even have tons of upvotes and a positive reputation... The ban seems to have been automated, so I'll look into fixing this issue, when I have time and my health is good

Answer (score 4):

First, sorry to hear about your health! I hope you can recover quickly.

The best advice I can point you to is the "*How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?*" section of the Meta post: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/307535)

A couple of high points from that post:

- **Do not delete your posts.**
- If you're unable to improve your existing posts, you'll get the chance to post one new question or answer 6 months after your last question/answer. If that post is positively received, you may be able to continue posting questions/answers; if not, the ban will be reinstated.

The U&L site also has [a page in the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) that is similar.

---

Some advice above and beyond that:

- Your most recent U&L question is one that I'd consider borderline low-quality. Show the research (effort) you've taken to this point.
- Asking for ["learning materials"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off-topic here (excepting pointers to *official* documentation). "Good" documentation would be subjective.
- Punctuation helps.
- Use the body of your post to set up your environment, efforts so far, and any relevant requirements.
- If I may, please refer to a Meta Q&A I posted earlier: [What else can I do to make my question well-received and improve my chances of getting answers?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/what-else-can-i-do-to-make-my-question-well-received-and-improve-my-chances-of-g). I noticed that while you have several StackExchange accounts, you haven't made your way through the U&L tour page for the "Informed" badge.

Comment: Thank you good sir for the help