# A question about UEFI network stack

Tags: support

I have a question about UEFI network stack and Linux. Where is the right place to put it?

Comment: Depends, what is the question? Linux is on topic on the main site, so I would guess your question would be fine here, but I can't tell without more details. But, off the top of my head, I can't really see how something about Linux networking wouldn't be on topic, what's making you doubt it?

Comment: I thought that the right website to put the question would be Unix&Linux but am banned to ask questions on Unix&Linux. So I decided to sort it out beforehand

Comment: @ccsann You are currently banned, which is an automatic thing that us mods can't do anything about, and it could have something to do with having deleted 50% of your questions (some of them not deleted by you directly though).  In some cases, deleting questions may cause a ban. Getting oneself unbanned is a matter of improving the quality of one's contributions. See also https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5504